# I want change loop for to stream

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, java-stream

I have a for loop and i want to change this for to stream and put a list can you help me ? is it possible do it something like that ?

```
for(int i=2;i<flightList.size();i=i+2){
        Root root = new Root();
        root.setAirport(flightList.get(i-1).split("\n")[1]);
        root.setCity_name(flightList.get(i-2).split(",")[0]);
        root.setCountry_name(flightList.get(i-2).split(",")[1].split("\n")[0]);
        flightMap.put(flightList.get(i).split("\n")[2],
                root);
    }


    List< String > flightListApi = flightTicketRequest.flightTicketFromList(keyword);
    flightListApi.stream().forEach(item->{
        //  System.out.println(item);
    });

    for(int i=0;i<flightListApi.size();i++){
        Root root = new Root();
        //IZM,Türkiye:Adnan Menderes Havalimanı:İzmir
        root.setAirport(flightListApi.get(i));
        root.setCountry_name(flightListApi.get(i).split(":")[0]);
        root.setAirport(flightListApi.get(i).split(":")[1]);
        root.setCity_name(flightListApi.get(i).split(":")[2]);
        flightMapAPi.put(flightListApi.get(i).split(",")[0],
                root);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert this into a Stream style approach.

```
Map<String, Root> flightMap = IntStream.range(2, flightList.size())
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    Root root = new Root();
                    root.setAirport(flightList.get(i-1).split("\n")[1]);
                    root.setCity_name(flightList.get(i-2).split(",")[0]);
                    root.setCountry_name(flightList.get(i-2).split(",")[1].split("\n")[0]);
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(flightList.get(i).split("\n")[2], root);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));


Map<String, Root> flightMapAPi = flightListApi.stream()
                .map(item-> {
                    Root root = new Root();
                    //IZM,Türkiye:Adnan Menderes Havalimanı:İzmir
                    root.setAirport(item);
                    root.setCountry_name(item.split(":")[0]);
                    root.setAirport(item.split(":")[1]);
                    root.setCity_name(item.split(":")[2]);
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(item.split(",")[0], root);
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```